# Amazon Route 53 Pointer Record not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a problem with a PTR (Pointer) in Route53.

I want http://tradehubz.com to redirect to http://www.tradehubz.com.

From what I gathered, the way to do it is via the PTR record which should do a `HTTP Redirect (301)`?

**Example of Configuration on Route53**

[image: Example of Configuration on Route53]

**Ping Result**

[image: Result when doing a ping on www.tradehubz.com vs tradehubz.com]

Comment: I don't want to be using a A record to point to a static IP. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need both ptr and "A" record for www .. I don't know what PTR record has to do with 301 redirect as PTR is for setting up reverse IP lookup. and then you will need a server side redirect from non www to www.

Answer (score 3):

PTR record is for reverse DNS lookup or reverse DNS resolution is the determination of a domain name that is associated with a given IP address using the Domain Name Service (DNS) of the Internet.  DNS is not capable of acting like an HTTP redirect in any way. I think you should create "A" record for WWW and setup server side redirect.

Answer (score 0):

DNS can do a lot more than you think it can. But I don't think you should be playing with records you have no clue about. Although I think an .htaccess rewrite rule makes more makes more sense ~ not every domain name is going to have hosting. Thus you create a CNAME (Canonical Name record) that directs to another url.

In this case it seems like your wanting to cover your bases in case someone goes to www. Then I would agree to use an IPv4 address (A- IPv4) or IPv6 (AAA-IPv6) record~

Set the a record - then go learn about rewrites (.htacess) server side changes respond faster than DNS records.